# strtotime() returns zero when changing timezone

Tags: php, timezone

```
$t = '01:00:00';
strtotime('January 1, 1970,'.$t)
```

Returns zero as soon as I change timezone to:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
```

How come?
I would like to get the amount of time stored in $t in seconds.

Thanks / E

Comment: What timezone are you changing from?

Comment: try this echo strtotime('now');

Comment: this is ok. So this work correct

Comment: so its not the problem with the timezone or strtotime. read mat answer  and check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: strtotime returns Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

Comment: When I try to check the system timezone by:
    echo date("e");

I get:

    Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case...... spelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /Library/WebServer/Documents/calendar/temp.php on line 3
Europe/Berlin

If I set the timezone to UTC instead of 'Europe/Stockholm' I get the right value: 3600. But then it of course gives me the wrong time.

Comment: @user1403350: **zero is the right value for strtotime for 1am on Jan 1st 1970 in Stockholm**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jan 1st 1970, 01h00 Stockholm time **should** return 0. It's Jan 1st 1970 00h00 in UTC.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the concept.
So basically if I always add one hour (the difference between UTC and Europe/Stockholm time) I will get the right answer. When setting the timezone to 'Europe/Stockholm' does it automatically handle the  daylight saving difference? I couldn't find any information regarding this.

Comment: Yes, DST is handled. No, always adding an hour won't "work", because of DST. If you want UTC, specify UCT. If you want Stockholm time, use Stockholm time. If you want to stay sane, always, always store and manipulate UTC, and use the "end-user" timezone only for input and display.

Comment: It now works as it should! I did like you said, went with UTC for everything. Thanks for the tip, it became a lot easier to handle.